# can any body please tell me how to resize the image to specific size and curve using canvas

Tags: javascript, css, html, image, canvas

I have a application that user will upload a big image, I have other small image in my application. I want to resize and curve the uploaded image using canvas.

I am using the below code. It is curving the image but I am unable to resize the image.

```
var imageObj1 = new Image();
var imageObj2 = new Image();
imageObj1.src = "./images/mug_center.jpg"
imageObj2.src = dataImage;
var x1 = imageObj2.width / 2;
var x2 = imageObj2.width;
var y1 = 19; // curve depth
var y2 = 0;
var eb = (y2*x1*x1 - y1*x2*x2) / (x2*x1*x1 - x1*x2*x2);
var ea = (y1 - eb*x1) / (x1*x1);
// variable used for the loop
var currentYOffset;
for(var x = 0; x < imageObj2.width; x++) {
    // calculate the current offset
    currentYOffset = (ea * x * x) + eb * x;
    ctx.drawImage(imageObj2,x,0,1,imageObj2.height,x,currentYOffset,1,imageObj2.height);
}
var img = c.toDataURL("image/png");
```

Comment: Those last 2 variables in `ctx.drawImage` will let you resize the image that gets drawn to the canvas.

Comment: hi mark if i change that params image is not curving.

Answer (score 0):

**Here's one way:**

- Draw your curved version of the image on a temporary canvas.
- `context.scale` to scale your main canvas
- `context.drawImage(tempCanvas...)` to draw the curved temp canvas to the main canvas.

[image]

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;


var imageObj2=new Image();
imageObj2.onload=start;
imageObj2.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/multple/reef.jpg";
function start(){

  curvedScale(1.5)

}

function curvedScale(scale){
  var tempCanvas=document.createElement('canvas');
  var tctx=tempCanvas.getContext('2d');
  tempCanvas.width=imageObj2.width*scale;
  tempCanvas.height=imageObj2.height*scale*3;
  var x1 = imageObj2.width / 2;
  var x2 = imageObj2.width;
  var y1 = 19; // curve depth
  var y2 = 0;
  var eb = (y2*x1*x1 - y1*x2*x2) / (x2*x1*x1 - x1*x2*x2);
  var ea = (y1 - eb*x1) / (x1*x1);
  // variable used for the loop
  var currentYOffset;
  var maxY=0;
  for(var x = 0; x < imageObj2.width; x++) {
    // calculate the current offset
    currentYOffset = (ea * x * x) + eb * x;
    if(currentYOffset>maxY){maxY=currentYOffset;}
    tctx.drawImage(
      imageObj2,
      x,0,1,imageObj2.height,
      x,currentYOffset,1,imageObj2.height
    );
  }
  ctx.scale(scale,scale);
  ctx.drawImage(tempCanvas,0,0,tempCanvas.width,tempCanvas.height);
  ctx.scale(-scale,-scale);
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<h4>Canvas with 1.50X scale</h4>
<canvas id="canvas" width=600 height=400></canvas>
<h4>Original Image</h4>
<img src='https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/multple/reef.jpg'>
```